# is it possible to change color/font on specific text in TextArea?

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, sapui5

I have a TextArea element in my SAPUI5 app to let the users paste data into. They copy the data from Excel and paste it into the TextArea, the data is 3 cols by x rows. Once they click a button I grab the data and check for any errors found. What I want to do is: highlight(or something else) the specific set of data that contains the error so they know what to fix. Currently I'm adding text next to the row to show where to look at, but this can create a lot of confusion for the user.

These are my code snippets
XML View

```
<FlexBox direction="Column" alignItems="Center">
        <items>
            <Label text="Paste excel data inside box below (don't enter column headers)" design="Bold" required="true"/>
            <TextArea id="input" rows="30" cols="80" />
            <Button id="processBtn" text="Process" press="onProcess"/>
            <Button id="clearBtn" text="Clear" press="onClear"/>
        </items>
    </FlexBox>
```

Code to update TextArea with errors after errors have been found

```
displayInputErrors: function(faultyRows){        
        var inputText = "";

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(faultyRows.indexOf(i) != -1)
                inputText += data[i].NSN + "\t" + data[i].QTY + "\t" + data[i].PRICE +" *** Row("+(i+1)+")\n";  
            else
                inputText += data[i].NSN + "\t" + data[i].QTY + "\t" + data[i].PRICE +"\n";
        }

        inputControls.textInput.setValue(inputText);
    },
```

This is what data looks like now once updated.
1234566 line 234
123455  frts 2-43 ***Row(2)
1234566 line 234
12345a5  frts 243 ***Row(4)
1234566 line 234 
123455  frts 243

One problem with this is that the user needs to also remove "***Row(x)" besides fixing the problem. If they leave anything behind it will be flagged as having an error. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend to transfer excel data to the sap.ui.Table with sap.m.Input control in cells. From now on, you can highlight the error lines right in the input (by ValueState property).

Comment: The user has to be able to fix the data on the spot, hence why I'm using TextArea. They can have several hundred lines of code, so signaling the line somewhere else might not be very useful imo. Also tables are not very good at displaying large amounts of data.

Comment: Tables are designed to display large amounts of data :) And cell that highlighted with a red frame will help user to fix it on the spot.

Comment: A working demo in fiddle or plunkr could easily help to sort out the issue. As your explanation about validating error is quite confusing

Comment: AndriiNaumovych - I disagree with that, at least from my experience and what I've read on through SAPUI5 best practices (I'm talking 300+ rows).
@santhosh, - Unfortunately I can't do that as it is work code and can't just put it up online. I decided to go with the solution of simply replacing the text on the TextArea to show only the data that contains errors. For what I've read what I was trying to do is not doable.